# Why my createState() is wrong? i dont know how i can resolve that

Tags: flutter, state, statefulwidget

I have an error on my flutter code, i dont know where is the error, if i put a getter, it dissappier, but... i dont know if that soluction is great.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZjOr.png)
Class 'MyHomePage' can't define method 'createState' and have field 'StatefulWidget.createState' with the same name.
Try converting the method to a getter, or renaming the method to a name that doesn't conflict.dart(conflicting_method_and_field)

but if i put an getter:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrINZ.png)

thanks you!

How i can resolve that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

replace your line with create state line with

```
@override
State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
```

For the best practice do not write this manually.

just write stful and press enter it will auto generate stateful class for you & you have to write class name.That's the shortcut of generate basic structure of stateful class

Comment: Thanks for the anwser! But the problem persists on my code, idk if the problem is with an archive on my flutter program maybe